# Fixed effect regression randomly returning NaN despite variation in R

Tags: r, linear-regression

I am using the `flem` from the `lfe` package to perform a regression analysis with fixed effects, many variables and interaction terms. I run multiple versions of the model, subsetting it with different segments of the population data to test if the results are consistent when the population is divided. However, when I segment the data, sometimes the regression results produce values of "NaN" in the output for specific interaction terms. Normally I would have assumed this is because one of the predictor variables was dropped out by segmenting, but I have checked the data and ensured that in all cases there remains variation for all the different predictors and interaction terms.

For example, one output gives me the following when I run the `summary` function:

```
   felm(formula = `outcome` ~ interact_var * (var_a + var_b + var_c + var_d) + interact_var * (var_e + var_b + var_c + var_d) + interact_var * (var_f + var_b + var_c + var_d) + interact_var * (var_g + var_b + var_c + var_d) + interact_var * (var_h + var_b + var_c + var_d) | `reg_fe` + `year_fe`, data = test_df_subset1) 

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-5.4313 -0.5677  0.1815  0.8067  2.5138 

Coefficients:
                                           Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
interact_var                       0.1643891  0.5562948   0.296   0.7676  
var_a                               -0.1576999  0.9188796  -0.172   0.8637  
var_b                         0.0152125  0.0059798   2.544   0.0110 *
var_c                                    -0.0005312  0.0016183  -0.328   0.7428  
var_d                                     -0.0490306  0.0496711  -0.987   0.3236  
var_e                      0.1848361  0.0841699   2.196   0.0281 *
var_f                       0.0621892  0.1957733   0.318   0.7508  
var_g                              -0.4822536  0.9025295  -0.534   0.5931  
var_h                               -0.3524088  0.9221887  -0.382   0.7024  
interact_var:var_a           -0.5312700  0.5821622  -0.913   0.3615  
interact_var:var_b    -0.0058413  0.0078052  -0.748   0.4543  
interact_var:var_c                  -0.0021580  0.0022033  -0.979   0.3274  
interact_var:var_d                  -0.0288419  0.0688507  -0.419   0.6753  
interact_var:var_e -0.1510189  0.1642956  -0.919   0.3580  
interact_var:var_f  -0.4977483  0.5286977  -0.941   0.3465  
interact_var:var_g          -0.0993812  0.5265530  -0.189   0.8503  
interact_var:var_h                  NaN         NA     NaN      NaN  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.208 on 5055 degrees of freedom
  (12044 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared(full model): 0.1114   Adjusted R-squared: 0.0567 
Multiple R-squared(proj model): 0.01643   Adjusted R-squared: -0.04408 
F-statistic(full model):2.037 on 311 and 5055 DF, p-value: < 2.2e-16 
F-statistic(proj model): 4.967 on 17 and 5055 DF, p-value: 7.828e-11
```

Where randomly the final interaction term "interact_var:var_h" drops out as "NaN". However, another segmenting of the data, which actually includes the entire previous sample + more observations from the original entire dataset, suddenly causes another interaction term to drop out:

```
Call:
   felm(formula = `outcome` ~ interact_var * (var_a + var_b + var_c + var_d) + interact_var * (var_e + var_b + var_c + var_d) + interact_var * (var_f + var_b + var_c + var_d) + interact_var * (var_g + var_b + var_c + var_d) + interact_var * (var_h + var_b + var_c + var_d) | `reg_fe` + `year_fe`, data = test_df_subset1and2)  

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-5.4743 -0.6118  0.1263  0.8130  2.3714 

Coefficients:
                                           Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
interact_var                      -0.4650499  0.0884383  -5.258 1.46e-07 ***
var_a                              0.3147956  0.2803823   1.123 0.261556    
var_b                         0.0096290  0.0019474   4.945 7.67e-07 ***
var_c                                     -0.0001796  0.0005019  -0.358 0.720423    
var_d                                    -0.0356512  0.0152004  -2.345 0.019011 *  
var_e                     0.1097865  0.0242857   4.521 6.18e-06 ***
var_f                      -0.0559867  0.0538596  -1.039 0.298582    
var_g                             0.0907108  0.2748201   0.330 0.741346    
var_h                               0.1136692  0.2795566   0.407 0.684300    
interact_var:var_a                  NaN         NA     NaN      NaN    
interact_var:var_b     0.0013611  0.0027188   0.501 0.616642    
interact_var:var_c                  -0.0023681  0.0007438  -3.184 0.001454 ** 
interact_var:var_d                   0.0036577  0.0228342   0.160 0.872737    
interact_var:var_e -0.1762468  0.0503358  -3.501 0.000463 ***
interact_var:var_f  -0.2663606  0.1556181  -1.712 0.086973 .  
interact_var:var_g           0.4000851  0.0710884   5.628 1.84e-08 ***
interact_var:var_h            0.4430805  0.1706635   2.596 0.009429 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.089 on 37158 degrees of freedom
  (86598 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared(full model): 0.08458   Adjusted R-squared: 0.07556 
Multiple R-squared(proj model): 0.0184   Adjusted R-squared: 0.008734 
F-statistic(full model): 9.38 on 366 and 37158 DF, p-value: < 2.2e-16 
F-statistic(proj model): 13.33 on 17 and 37158 DF, p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

As you can see, now there are no "NaN"s for "interact_var:var_h", however suddenly "interact_var:var_a" yields "NaN"s despite the previous sample having variation for these indicators, and this new sample including the previous sample and additional observations.

In both cases, the “x observations deleted due to missingness” is unrelated to this, as these other observations are discarded for completely different reasons (and were discarded in the full data sample, prior to these "NaN"s emerging).

I apologize for being unable to provide original code/data at this stage as the data is sensitive. However, has anyone encountered this problem? Does anyone know how to stop the regression results from inexplicably dropping to NaN, despite their being variation? Is there another package to run multiple fixed effects and these interaction terms that might not cause this issue?

Comment: I **strongly** suspect that this is due to multicollinearity. You could use `caret::findLinearCombos` on the problematic subsets to see what's going on ...

Comment: I tried your suggestion and received: ```Error in qr.default(object) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)``` Would that indicate a multicollinearity issue?

Comment: Not sure. I'm suggesting (`X <- model.matrix(formula = ..., data = test_df_subset1and2); caret::findLinearCombox(X)`.  Is that what you did?)

Comment: Okay, now I ran what you suggested and it returned ```$linearCombos
$linearCombos[[1]]
[1] 2 1


$remove
[1] 2``` for the first dataframe and ```$linearCombos
$linearCombos[[1]]
[1] 2 1


$remove
[1] 2```
for the second data frame.

Comment: OK, now look at columns 1 and 2 and figure out why they're multicollinear ...  (column 1 is probably the intercept, does column 2 have no variability?) `sapply(X, 2, sd)` ...

Comment: I must have done something wrong inputing the formula, because the matrix it formed is two columns, 1 with the intercept and the other with the entire formula. Ever row is 1. I took away the fixed effects and this now produced full matrices. So the output is now: ```$linearCombos
$linearCombos[[1]]
[1] 18  2 11 17


$remove
[1] 18``` and ```$linearCombos
$linearCombos[[1]]
[1] 18  2 11 17


$remove
[1] 18``` But there appears to be variability in these columns.

Comment: right; the "no variability" is only relevant if we're looking at collinearity between the intercept and a single other column.  Otherwise you need to see why those 4 (in this case) columns are redundant (i.e., any one column can be created by a linear combination of the others).

Comment: Ah I see, this makes sense. All of the columns that are co-linear are colinear because they are the interaction terms that share the interact variable. When I remove the suggested column (18)'s interaction term from the equation, the NaNs disappear and I get the desired estimates. Is there a way to overcome this then and keep all of the terms given that the colinear columns are only so because of the interaction?